# Check if certain numbers are in a string

Tags: java, string, numbers

I wanna be able to know if the string contains whatever is inside the double var "nN".

I've tried

```
if(!line.matches(nN)) {

}
```

Here is more of my code as someone asked

```
public double n; 
private int x = 31; //maximun  power for the int varible
private boolean number = false;
private double origanalN;
private double nN;
private double array[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31};
private int countNum[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31};
private int i = 0;

private String line = " ";
private double checkIf;
public void firstCalculation() {
    origanalN = n;
    while(x >= 0 || number == true) {
        nN = Math.pow(2, x);
        n = n - nN;
    //  System.out.println("\t\t\t " + n + " \t" + x);
        if(n == 0) {
            System.out.println(n + " equals 0 on the " + x + "th power");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(n < 0) {
            n = n + nN;
        }
        if(n != origanalN) {
            if(!line.matches(nN)) {

            }
            line += nN + " ";
            array[x] = n;
            System.out.println("\t\t" + array[x] + " " + line);
        }
        //  System.out.println(n + "\t\t");
        x--;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the help center before posting

Comment: Could post all your code and show that you really tried something

Comment: You could use a regular expression

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also what programming language are you using? More detail!!!

Comment: That doesn't mean post all your code. Post the code that is relevant. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Again Jaden, please read the help center before posting.

Comment: it says java as a tag. Also ive searched it many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try converting `double nN` to a string and see if your `String line` contains it with if statement:

```
if (line.contains(Double.toString(nN))) {
    code...
}
```